# Send Multiple commands using Netmiko

Tags: command, router

I am struggling to send multiple commands to multiple hosts , i am using commands input from a file:

*commands.txt*

```
sh ip int bri
sh run
sh ver
```

*hosts.txt*

```
router 1
router 2
router 3
```

I then run following

from **future** import print_function from netmiko import ConnectHandler ##For SSH import re import getpass while True: #create loop for whole program     username = input ("Enter Username")     jumphostpassword = getpass.getpass("Enter Jumphost Password")     elif (op == 2):             TACACSpassword = getpass.getpass ("Enter TACACS Password")             elif(in1=="c"):                      commandsfile = input ("Please Enter CommandsFile path as c:/example/ \n :")                     hostsfile = input ("Please Enter Hosts path as c:/example/ \n :")                    # hosts = open((hostsfile) , "r")                     hosts = [hosts for hosts  in (hosts.strip() for hosts in open(hostsfile)) if hosts]                     for host1  in hosts:                                     with open ( host1+".txt","w") as file:                                             commands1 = open( (commandsfile), "r+")                                             jumphost = {'device_type': 'linux','ip': '172.27.200.26', 'username': (username),'password': (jumphostpassword)}                                              net_connect = ConnectHandler(**jumphost)                                             output = net_connect.send_command("ssh " +str(host1))                                             print (output)                                             else:                                                     output = net_connect.send_command(TACACSpassword)                                                     print (output)                                                     output = net_connect.send_command("term leng 0")                                                     print (output)                                                                                                               cmd1 = [cmd1 for cmd1  in (cmd1.strip() for cmd1 in open(commandsfile)) if cmd1]                                                     for cmd1 in commands1:                                                                                                                print ("File saved in c:\saad\saad.txt ")                                                         output += net_connect.send_config_set(cmd1)                                                         print (output)                                                          net_connect.disconnect                                                     print ("File saved in c:\saad\saad.txt ")                                                     file.write(output)                                      file.close()                     continue

Answer (score 1):

Place your IPs in ips.csv file in the following format...

```
Host
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
```

Then use the following code, usage python code.py -c ips.csv

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import getpass
import re
import csv
import paramiko
import netmiko
from argparse import ArgumentParser
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser(description='Arguments:')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--csv', required=True, action='store',
                        help='Location of CSV file of IPs')


args = parser.parse_args()

ssh_username = 'yoursshusername'


ssh_password = 'yoursshpassword'

with open(args.csv, 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for device_row in reader:
        try:
            ssh_session = ConnectHandler(device_type='cisco_ios',
                    ip=device_row['Host'],
                    username=ssh_username, password=ssh_password)
            print '********* {0} *********'.format(device_row['Host'
                    ])

        # Specify your commands here, you can add more commands just follow the same syntax
             print ssh_session.send_command('show running-config | i hostname')
        # Specify exceptions here 
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print ('{0}'.format(device_row['Host']),"Authenticaiton Problem!")
            pass
```